# JSONPath :contains filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json, jsonpath

Hey all, I was wondering if any knew of a way to use a regular expression or wildcard operator (or pehaps `'%LIKE%'` in SQL) so I could use JSONPath to do searching within a large set of JSON data.

For instance (and yes, I'm parsing, not `eval( )`ing my data in the app):

```
var obj = eval ( '({ "hey": "can you find me?" })' );
```

And I'd like to be able to look through the data like this:

```
$.[?(@.hey:contains(find))] // (in jQuery terminology)
```

where the contents of an argument is part or all of the value in the `{ "key" : "value" }` pairs in my data.

At the moment I have only found documentation on `>`, `<`, `=`, and `!=` relational operators, which don't give me that much flexibility.

Does anyone know a way I can just **just** JSONPath to find this data (without having to loop through all the entries)?

I don't want to use Dojo's JSONQuery, as this would require another library.  However, it lets you do this, here their example:

```
[?description~‘*the*’]
```

Ask me if you want more clarification of the question.

Comment: oh yeah, here's the documentation - http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

nevermind, guys, found a way to do it by just using ECMA inside of JSONPath, though this is not a native selector / operator.  Simply used:

```
$.[?(/find/.test(@.hey))]
```

the RegExp test( ) method (which JSONPath `eval`s behind the scenes).

If anyone has a better answer, though, let me know.

Answer (score 8):

Also, may be it will be useful for someone.
[Link to JSONPath Notation](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html)

It works for me (JMeter 4.0)

`=~`

> Match a JavaScript regular expression. For example, [?(@.description =~ /cat.*/i)] matches items whose description starts with cat (case-insensitive).

Answer (score 4):

If anyone wants the contains solution in Java then this works with JsonPath

```
Filter<?> filter = Filter.filter(Criteria.where("hey").regex(Pattern.compile(".*find.*")));
System.out.println(JsonPath.read(json, "$..[?]", filter));
```

Imports

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Criteria;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Filter;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
```

Answer (score 2):

**=~** worked for me.
Tested with Jmeter 5.3 JSON Extractor.

Answer (score -1):

You can use LIKE in jsonpath this way:

```
$.[?(@.hey like_regex '.*find.*')]
```