# JPath for partial query match

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

I'm trying to learn json jpath query. I have successfully been able to return data based on exact searches.

For example at the site: https://jsonpath.com/ I can successfully retrieve the type of phone based on phone number:

JSON

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

Query

```
$.[?(@.number== '0123-4567-8888')].type
```

However I can't find any examples that show me how to match a partial search result. I'm trying to write a query where I provide just "0123" and hence get back both "home" and "iPhone" returned as results.How can I do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003252/jsonpath-contains-filter

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the example at the link but can't get it to work. Still returns no match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `=~` match [filter operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) which allows providing a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) instead of strict value so given you amend your query like:

```
$.phoneNumbers[?(@.number=~/.*0123.*/)].type
```

you will get both types as the result:

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Dang Dmitri, is there anything you don't know?! :D Thanks